# Document root not displaying

Tags: php

I have a script which uses its absolute path to all other included files; the script is going to be execute as a cron job. When I run the script in the terminal the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` returns a null value, but in the browser it returns the correct document root.

What would cause this problem?

Comment: This is not an error. It is expected behavior. The CLI behaves differently from other SAPIs. You can get a nice rundown of how it does so in the [PHP manual docs on the subject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php)

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that `$_SERVER` variables are provided by the executing environment. When you run the script on the command line, there is no HTTP server.

So, you can't use things like `DOCUMENT_ROOT` - what would that be, when there's no Apache configuration setting it?

Instead, you can use variables like `__FILE__`, which is the full path to the script. Perhaps `dirname` of that one or more times will get you to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect `$_SERVER` to be defined only when the script is actually running in a webserver, not when it's run by the standalone command-line PHP interpreter.  That value only makes sense in a server context.  If the script is meant to run as a cron job, it shouldn't rely on that variable.

Answer (score 1):

When php is executed in CLI mode, it behaves differently, including by not setting `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.  For a good list of `$_SERVER` values and other tools available at command line, try executing `<?php echo phpinfo();`

As a CLI script, you should still have access to `__FILE__` to find out what the file you're running is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Magento then instead of using

> $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

or

> `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`

I would suggest you to use

> dirname(Mage::getRoot())

this will give you root folder of your Magento store, hope this helps.

Cheers
S

Answer (score 0):

I have the need of executing the same scripts in different server environments and have run into the issue of finding the public root of a site especially with command line php. I got sick of editing paths so I wrote a function that finds the root on all of my server environments. I am sure there is a better way but works great for me.
some examples of what directory structures it works on:

```
'/var/www/magento/some/folder/'
'/home/user/html/some/folder/'
'/home/user/public_html/some/folder/'


function getSiteRoot() {
    /*
    ' Returns the root of any of your development/live site as long as the $home array
    ' contains a unique folder name. Define your public directories in this array and the
    ' building function will break when it hits this directory.
    */
    $a = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'');
    $b = explode('/', $a);
    $home = array("html","public_html","magento"); //add your public folders here
    $str = '';
    foreach ($b as $c) {
        $str.= $c . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '';
            if(in_array($c, $home)) {
                break;
            }
    }
    return $str;
}
```